# file editing shell but i permission denied

Tags: bash, shell, permission-denied

`sudo echo "sadfsadf" > /etc/apache2/mods-available/dir.conf`

I ran the command with `sudo` but it returned the error: "permission denied:

Why does this command not work?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo xxx > file` does not work as expected. `xxx` is executed as root, but the filewrite (`>`) is still 'executed' as the current user.

`sudo -s` and then execute the command with the pipe.